# rCharts - Data label for Highcharts bubble chart

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts, bubble-chart

I'm using rCharts to create a Highcharts bubble chart and have trouble changing the bubble label. In this example, I want the branch name to appear in the bubble instead of the default y. Sample data and the code I'm using:

```
branch <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
cases <- c('100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600')
prop <- c('600', '500', '400', '300', '200', '100')
units <- c('6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1')
size <- c('large', 'large', 'large', 'medium', 'small', 'small')
df <- data.frame(branch, cases, prop, units, size)

library(rCharts)

h1 <- hPlot(x = "prop", y = "units", data = df, type = "bubble", group = "size", size = "cases", name = "branch")

h1$plotOptions(bubble =list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, x = 0,
                                          formatter = "#! function() {
                                          return this.point.name;} !#"
                                          )))
```

All help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `format: "{point.name}"` instead of `formatter`?

Comment: @PawełFus Thank you  for your comment. Same as 'formatter', format: "{point.name}" only works for X and Y but doesn't work for branch.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in hPlot to use an unused colomn in your toolTip or plotOptions.

Try the following code, where instead of name Y is used:

```
branch <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
cases <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600)
prop <- c(600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100)
units <- c(6, 5,4, 3, 2, 1)
size <- c('large', 'large', 'large', 'medium', 'small', 'small')
df <- data.frame(branch, cases, prop, units, size)

library(rCharts)

h1 <- hPlot(x = "prop", y = "units", type = "bubble", group = "size", size = "cases", name = "branch", data = df)

h1$plotOptions(series=list(dataLabels=list(enabled=TRUE, format = '{y}')))

h1
```

As you'll see this will show the y value in the bubbles. You can show the x values as well. But thats it. This is due to the structure of the bubble chart. However there is a workaround for this. See https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/289 for more information on this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have no problem with displaying X and Y as the bubble label, the problem lies with using a column not used in the chart (like branch in this example). I have tried re-arranging the dataframe, but that also doesn't work. The workaround would require the data to be entered manually which is not ideal for large dataset.

Comment: Thats true, but unfortunately there does not seem to be any other way. Maybe try a different library? I'm sure Highcharts is not the only one capable of producing bubble charts.